# Submit form built with Framework7 using ajax

Tags: ajax, html-framework-7

I am developing hybrid mobile app using [Framework7](http://framework7.io/). I have a registration form which needs to be submitted using ajax on click of submit button. I am using below given code for the same. But it's not working.

```
$$(document).on('pageInit', function() {
   $$('#myFrom').on('submit',function(){
     ....
     alert('hello world');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try submitting your form on the **click of the button** instead of the **submit of the form**

Assuming your button has the ID btnSubmit

```
$$(document).on('pageInit', function() { 
      $$("#btnSubmit").on('click', function(){
       //run Ajax script here
       });
});
```

Comment: if you do this the html5 form verification will not working

Answer (score 0):

```
$$(document).on('click','#btnSubmit',function(){
   alert('hello world');
});
```

Try above. In Framework7 $$('.class/ID') will not work.